# TypeScript Type 'Record<string, string>' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why is this wrong? I've had similar issues with this and never figured it out. Whenever I do this:

```
    type dataType = {
        [key: string]: string | Record<string, string>;
    };

    const rawData = [
        {
            name: 'XXXX',
            commission: 'XXXX',
            psc: 'XXX XX',
            ico: 'XXXXXXXX',
            address: 'XXXXXXX',
            city: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
        },
    ];
    const createData = ({ name, commission, ico, address, psc, city }: dataType) => {
        return { name, commission, legal: { name, ico, address, city: `${psc} ${city}` } };
    };

    const rows: dataType[] = [createData(rawData[0])];
```

This should theoretically be working fine, should it not? The dataType is a type of an object with any key that is string with a value of either string or another object. Why does this not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `createData` should not take a `dataType` object as its argument. The way you wrote it, `name`, `ico` and `address` might be of type `Record<string, string>`, arriving at the signature

```
const createData: ({ name, commission, ico, address, psc, city }: dataType) => {
    name: string | Record<string, string>;
    commission: string | Record<string, string>;
    legal: {
        name: string | Record<string, string>;
        ico: string | Record<...>;
        address: string | Record<...>;
        city: string;
    };
}
```

These records inside the `legal` object are invalid when you try to assign the result to a `dataType` variable.

Instead, use

```
const createData = ({ name, commission, ico, address, psc, city }: Record<string, string>) => …
```

which is the proper type fitting your `rawData`. (You might want to be more precise and define an interface with the exact properties).

Answer (score 2):

[image: Sample usage]

Cause name can be `string | Record<string,string>`, so the *legal.name* in the return type could be `string | Record<string,string>` which means the type of *legal* should be `Record<string, string | Record<string,string>>;`

However, you defined return type of *createData* is *dataType*, that means type of *legal* can't cover the real type you return. Your define lead th cycle, try write another return type for your function.

Personally, I don't recommend you write type that way.

```
type DataType = {
  name: string,
  commission: string,
  psc: string,
  ico: string,
  address: string,
  city: string,
};

type AnotherDataType = {
  name: string,
  commission: string,
  legal: Partial<DataType>
}
```

might be better.